# Why is a contractor's profit considered a producer surplus instead of being complementary with marginal utility?

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, consumer-surplus, producer-surplus

Do economists currently not view contractors as labor?

*I suggest producer surplus be exclusively exclusive material (for otherwise even mining and logging would not need withstand fixed-startup costs if access were elastic to other vertical horizons) or expiring payment installments and consumer surplus over leisure value as utility enumerable, and 0x/0y gradient in stasis, book-made.*

Comment: What is with the word salad in italics?

Comment: I'm explaining why contractor profit is marginal utility value of contractors and surplus value should be considered expiring payment installments tapered price controls alone.

Comment: I give up. $~~$

Answer (score 1):

I'll take for granted you mean housing contractors.

A contractor owns a business that sells (produces) a service. From the standpoint of your question, they are the producer and the homeowner is the consumer.

The issue of wages paid by that business, including wages paid to the contractor themself, is a separate matter.

Comment: Why does the type of contractor matter?